# Gantt Charts & Pivotal Tracker

Tags: gantt-chart, pivotaltracker

Does anyone know of a good gantt chart to integrate with Pivotal tracker, or another solution?

I did the free trial of gantto and was not very impressed. Unfortunately I have not been able to find any other real solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please advise which tool you used to create the gantt chart for a pivotal tracker project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What problem are you trying to solve? Usually waterfall methodologies (which use Gantt charts) and Agile methodologies (which Tracker embodies) are mutually exclusive.

That said, take a look at the [Third Party Tools page](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/thirdpartytools) on the Tracker website; some of those may help.